npm install error, looking for package.json in a nested directory
im on an ec2 ubuntu instance (24.04), with npm v9.2.0 & node v18.19.1, and i attached my git repo to my remote and pulled the code.  i am getting this error though whenever i try to npm install
the project is react & vite, and when i goto my project root dir, and do npm install, i get:
`root@ip-172-31-17-191:/var/www/project# npm i
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /var/www/project/.eslint-rules/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/project/.eslint-rules/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent`

Obviously, it's looking for a package.json inside my eslint-rules directory, but why? that isnt the root of the project.  i have a package.json at my root.  my eslint-rules directory has a polyfill rule for my eslint in dev.
inside my package.json i have these in my devDependencies:
"devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^5.0.5",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.8",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-window": "^1.8.8",
    "eslint-plugin-structured-clone-import": "file:.eslint-rules",
    "rollup-plugin-visualizer": "^5.12.0"
  },

when i remove the "eslint-plugin-structured-clone-import" line it can fully install all the other packages, but when it's there it hits the error mentioned.  I've set this repo up on my local, AND other ubuntu VMs, so why all of a sudden is npm trying to find a package.json file inside the .eslint-rules?
I tried to npm init in the root of my project again, just to make sure it was looking at the root level package.json, but it gives the same error.
and yes, I made sure I was in the root of the project repo before using npm install.
update with logs:
extra info, the logs are here:
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-10-05T18_09_58_432Z-debug-0.log
logs:

0 verbose cli /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/npm
1 info using npm@9.2.0
2 info using node@v18.19.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/share/nodejs/npm/npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:/var/www/project/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:/root/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 11ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm i
21 verbose argv "i"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 2ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 5ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 6ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/root/.npm/_logs/2024-10-05T18_09_58_432Z-
26 verbose logfile /root/.npm/_logs/2024-10-05T18_09_58_432Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 10ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 31ms
31 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
32 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 0ms
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
34 silly logfile done cleaning log files
35 timing idealTree:init Completed in 1085ms
36 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
37 silly idealTree buildDeps
38 silly fetch manifest eslint-plugin-structured-clone-import@file:.eslint-rules
39 silly placeDep ROOT eslint-plugin-structured-clone-import@ REPLACE for: test-app2@0.1.0 want: file:.eslint-rules
40 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 17ms
41 timing idealTree:node_modules/eslint-plugin-structured-clone-import Completed in 0ms
42 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 18ms
43 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 17ms
44 timing idealTree Completed in 1121ms
45 timing command:i Completed in 1130ms
46 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/project/.eslint-rules/package.json'
47 verbose cwd /var/www/project
48 verbose Linux 6.8.0-1016-aws
49 verbose node v18.19.1
50 verbose npm  v9.2.0
51 error code ENOENT
52 error syscall open
53 error path /var/www/project/.eslint-rules/package.json
54 error errno -2
55 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/project/.eslint-rules/package.json'
56 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
56 error enoent
57 verbose exit -2
58 timing npm Completed in 1186ms
59 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1728151798489
60 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1728151798491
61 verbose code -2
62 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
62 error     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-10-05T18_09_58_432Z-debug-0.log


The detailed log is showing you that this caused by eslint-plugin-structured-clone-import. Looking at your own package.json we see that you're loading that from a relative file path, so that directory better contain a package.json file, since you're telling npm that it's a node module, and node modules must have package.json files.
Easiest fix: just run npm init in that .eslint-rules dir, and accept the defaults. Done, now there's a 100% valid package.json file that npm can use to actually install that module. Bbecause it does: it doesn't just "read files from that dir" like it does when you use npm link, it literally installs it as a regular module in your node_modules dir instead.
